# Definition of the d-th power residue symbol

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

I started reading about the reciprocity law for polynomials over a finite field, and I came across the definition of the d-th power residue symbol:

Let $\Bbb F$ be a finite field with $q$ elements, $q=p^f$ ($p$ is the characteristic of $\Bbb F$), and let $A = \Bbb F[T]$. Let $P\in A$ be an irreducible polynomial, $d$ a divisor of $q-1$ and $a \in A$.

*Definition*: If $P$ does not divide $a$, let $(a/P)_d$ be the unique element of $\Bbb F^*$ such that $$a^{\frac{|P|-1}{d}}=\left(\frac{a}{P} \right)_d \pmod P$$

If $P|a$ define $(a/P)_d=0$. The symbol $(a/P)_d$ is called the d-th power residue symbol.

---

My question is: How do we know that $(a/P)_d$ is in $\Bbb F^*$ ? Why can't it be just any element of $(A/PA)^*$?

Comment: Since $P \in \mathbf{F}_q[T]$ is irreducible $(P)$ is a maximal ideal and $\mathbf{F}_q[T]/(P) \simeq \mathbf{F}_{q^m}$ where $m =  \deg(P)$. For $a \in \mathbf{F}_{q^m}^*$, $a^{q^m-1 }=1$ so the order of $a^{(q^m-1)/d}$ divides $d$ and for $d | q-1$ then $a^{(q^m-1)/d} \in \mathbf{F}_q^*$.

Comment: How did you conclude that $a^{(q^m-1})/d} \in F_q^*$? I understand everything else you said

Comment: $\mathbf{F}_q^*$ is a group with $q-1$ elements, so all those elements satisfy $x^{q-1}=1$. The polynomial $x^{q-1}-1$ has at most $q-1$ distinct roots in the field $\mathbf{F}_{q^m}$. Thus $c \in \mathbf{F}_{q^m}^*$ is in $\mathbf{F}_{q}^*$ iff it is a root of $x^{q-1}-1$ that is its order divides $q-1$ (this is also the way we prove those groups are cyclic)